# How to insert in a table with only an IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql-server, identity

Given a table with only an IDENTITY column, how do you insert a new row? I've tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
(Syntax error)

INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES()
(Syntax error)

INSERT INTO TABLE (Id) VALUES()
(Syntax error)
```

I am testing something and only need the IDENTITY column. It's not for production.  Otherwise, such a table can be used as a sequence generator, where no other columns are needed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql):

> `DEFAULT VALUES`
>   
> Forces the new row to contain the default values defined for each column.

So:

```
INSERT dbo.TABLE DEFAULT VALUES;
```

In addition:

1. [always use the schema prefix](http://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx)
2. [always terminate statements with semi-colons](http://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx)

Comment: Interesting, it appears to be part of SQL2003 (F222) but I have never seen the construction before ( INSERT INTO appears to be required though ). You learn something new every day :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use `IDENTITY_INSERT`. That way you can manually define which values you want to put in. Like so:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE ON ;

INSERT INTO TABLE (ID) VALUES (1), (2) ;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE OFF ;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
Insert into TableName Default values;
select Scope_identity();
```