# INSERT INTO.. SELECT with default keyword

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

Could not find anything related to this issue I am having, google only seems to return how to use the default keyword with INSERT INTO.. VALUES.

I have a table with the following columns:

| RecordBookID | Shop ID | Created | Expires |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uniqueidentifier | int | datetime | datetime |

RecordBookID has a default constraint that uses newid() as the default

I can run the following with expected results:

```sql
insert into GoodsIn_Record_Books (RecordBookID, ShopID, Created, Expires)
values (default, 201, '2022-07-22 11:24:00.000', '2022-12-31 23:59:00.000')
```

| RecordBookID | Shop ID | Created | Expires |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EA5CB534-1DC3-46FA-B4F4-8EE70B974956 | 201 | 2022-07-22 11:24:00.000 | 2022-12-31 23:59:00.000 |

However I want to insert into with data from another table like so:

```sql
insert into GoodsIn_Record_Books (RecordBookID, ShopID, Created, Expires)
select default, ShopID, '2022-07-22 11:24:00.000', '2022-12-31 23:59:00.000' from System_Shops
```

Where the default keyword uses the default value of RecordBookID

System_Shops table:

| ShopID | Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | WEST BAY | ... |
| 202 | TUMMEL VALLEY | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

Hopefully this makes sense, first post on here so apologies if it's wrong in any way.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried omitting `RecordBookID` from the `INSERT...SELECT` entirely? I would expect that to use the default constraint value.

Comment: :facepalm: You ever get the feeling you're overcomplicating something... cheers that's done it.

I'll mark as resolution if you add an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert in a table with only an IDENTITY column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40926/how-to-insert-in-a-table-with-only-an-identity-column)

Answer (score 1):

"Have you tried omitting RecordBookID from the INSERT...SELECT entirely? I would expect that to use the default constraint value." - @Dan Guzman

```
insert into GoodsIn_Record_Books (ShopID, Created, Expires)
select ShopID, '2022-07-22 11:24:00.000', '2022-12-31 23:59:00.000'
from System_Shops
```

Comment: Not sure why I shouldn't believe it

Answer (score 0):

The default values will get added by default if you dont specify the column in the insert and values statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(RecordBookID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT DF_tmp DEFAULT NEWID(),
 ShopID       INT,
 Created      DATETIME,
 Expires      DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #tmp(ShopID, Created, Expires)
VALUES(201, '2022-07-22 11:24:00.000', '2022-12-31 23:59:00.000');

select * from #tmp;
```

To insert a row with only the default values populated, it can be done like so:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, what you are trying to do should be possible with `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO
  dbo.GoodsIn_Record_Books AS g
USING
  dbo.System_Shops AS s
ON
  1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (RecordBookID, ShopID, Created, Expires)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, s.ShopID, '2022-07-22 11:24:00.000', '2022-12-31 23:59:00.000')
;
```

Please keep in mind two important things before using this, though:

1. You need the ability to stomach the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql).
2. You need to be aware that `MERGE` has been [reported to have numerous issues](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).